# Multiple plots on one graph (filled.contour)

Tags: r, plot, contour

I would like to combine multiple contour plots on one graph. My code is shown below.

```
d1<- read.table("/home/amy/Desktop/data.csv",sep=",",header=T)
ax<-d1$c1
ay<-d1$c2
library(MASS)
density1 <- kde2d(ax, ay)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
filled.contour(density1, xlab= "x axis",
    ylab= "y axis ", main ="first plot", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), 
    color.palette=colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','yellow','darkgreen','darkred')))


    bx<-d1$c3
    by<-d1$c4
    library(MASS)
    density2 <- kde2d(bx, by)
    filled.contour(density2, xlab= "x axis",
        ylab= "y axis ", main ="second plot", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), 
        color.palette=colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','yellow','darkgreen','darkred')))
```

An example for my data is shown below.

data.csv

```
c1     c2    c3    c4

23.7  36.8   45.6  32.5
45.5  23.8   67.5  34.8 
21.6  56.9   12.5  56.7
89.5  45.4   23.3  45.7
```

Comment: Before running your plotting code, do `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`, for example. Run `?par` for more information on `mfrow` and other graphical parameters for base graphics.

Comment: In mycase, par(mfrow=c(1,2)) doesn't work.  I just got the second plot instead of getting two plots.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `filled.contour` overrides any preexisting layout, so you can't plot two separate plots side by side. You could try to modify the function code to change the way it handles layouts (type `filled.contour` in the console to see the function code) to create a customized version of the function. An alternative is to use `levelplot` from the `lattice` package for your plots and then lay them out using `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package. Here's an example:

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)

# Fake data (taken from the fill.contour help examples)
x <- y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len = 100)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))

p1 = levelplot(cos(r^2)*exp(-r/(2*pi)))
p2 = levelplot(cos(r)*exp(-r/(2*pi)))

# Lay out both plots
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]